# reversed_array = 0 throws error shows syntax issue

Tags: python, python-3.x

This code:

```py
n = int(input())
arr = list(map(int, input().rstrip().split())
reversed_array = [] #I am just assigning the variable to an empty list. I don't understand.
for i in range(n):
    reversed_array.append(arr[n-i-1])

print(' '.join(str(i) for i in reversed_array))
```

Throws the following error:

```sh
    reversed_array = []
    ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax #Please explain
```

How can I fix it?

Comment: Count the parenthesis in the line before...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at line 2, expanded:

```
arr = list(
           map(
               int, input().rstrip().split()
              )
```

You need to close the parenthesis.

Answer (score 0):

Parentheses do not match when you defining the arr list.

```
n = int(input())
arr = list(map(int, input().rstrip().split())) # -> I added 1 more parenthesis
reversed_array = [] #I am just assigning the variable to an empty list. I don't understand.
for i in range(n):
    reversed_array.append(arr[n-i-1])

print(' '.join(str(i) for i in reversed_array))
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a missing closing bracket on line #2 for the list.
which is resulting into this error.

arr = list(map(int, input().rstrip().split())**)**